# I cant make function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQI7JGNB7W5G

How can I make my code;
go from .roundbutton to .roundbutton-active.

I tried js but that was not working.

```css
.round-button {
  width: 45%;
}

.round-button-active {
  -webkit-animation-name: example;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 150px;
  }
}

@keyframes d {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

.float_center {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  left: -30%;
  /* or right 50% */
  text-align: left;
}

.float_center>.child {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}

.round-button-circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #cfdcec;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ff006e;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}

.round-button-circle:hover {
  background: #9d0346;
}

.round-button a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #e2eaf3;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 4.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<video poster="key.png" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay loop>
  <!-- WCAG general accessibility recommendation is that media such as background video play through only once. Loop turned on for the purposes of illustration; if removed, the end of the video will fade in the same way created by pressing the "Pause" button  -->
  <source src="videoplayback.mp4" type="video/webm">
  <source src="videoplayback.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
<div class="round-button float_center">
  <div class="round-button-circle">
    <a href="#" class="round-button" ">PLAY</a></div></div>
```

Comment: Please provide your code which you have tried

Comment: Please post the code, and a clear explanation of (1) what you want to happen (2) what is currently happening (3) what you have tried. As it currently stands, your question is not suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: tried what !!! post you what have you tried !

Comment: don't use w3schools - it has bad practices and uses code that's incorrect or not strictly true, refer to MDN for documentation

Comment: you have no js? just html and css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based solely on what's given, a simple solution would be to select the roundbutton class and toggle an "active" class.

This could be done in jQuery through say a click element by

```
$("div.round-button").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

And that is assuming you are trying to select the div with the class of round button and not the anchor tag. Try not to have a child element with the same class as its parent as this might have been the reason why the JS wasn't working for you in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

with no jQuery add in javascript:

```
function toggleClass(element)
{
    if (element.classList == 'round-button') {
        element.classList.add('round-button-active');
        element.classList.remove('round-button');
    } else {
        element.classList.add('round-button');
        element.classList.remove('round-button-active');
    }
}
```

and add to div:
onClick="toggleClass(this)";

with jQuery add in javascript:

```
$('div.round-button').click(function()
{
    if (this.attr('class') == 'round-button') {
        this.addClass('round-button-active');
        this.removeClass('round-button');
    } else {
        this.addClass('round-button');
        this.removeClass('round-button-active');
    }
 })
```

Comment: don't recommend inline js / css - it's bad practice that leads to hard-to maintain code